# Can I open a code from Web Inspector through an IDE like WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to have a website code from Web Inspector (within Web Browser) downloaded as a folder in order to analyze it as a sample for my project. How could I do it? Thank you.

Comment: You mean... right click on the page -> save page as...?

Comment: You can copy paste html & css code of any website by inspecting it in your own website!

Comment: Thank you. @Lolpez I mean opening web inspector, not right click.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil It is supposed to work if I create an images folder, a styles folder, a scripts folder, and an index.html file? Then I copy each code in a file within its respective folder? Where should I save fonts and other documents? Thank you very much, sorry I'm pretty very beginner at JavaScript, what I want is to read a complex code and learn the JavaScript reference from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to copy all the files manually if you want to use the web inspector, however there are tools like [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/) that can help you crawl and retrieve the folders and source files of a web page and organize them nicely.

Remember that you can only retrieve client-side files like html, images, CSS, JavaScript and not server side like code. Also you should only use it for **educational purposes** and not for plagiarism.